# Where to start on creating a method that saves desired changes in a Tensor with PyTorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, autograd

I have two tensors that I am calculating the Spearmans Rank Correlation from, and I would like to be able to have PyTorch automatically adjust the values in these Tensors in a way that increases my Spearmans Rank Correlation number as high as possible.

I have explored autograd but nothing I've found has explained it simply enough.

Initialized tensors: 
`a=Var(torch.randn(20,1),requires_grad=True)` 
`psfm_s=Var(torch.randn(12,20),requires_grad=True)`

How can I have a loop of constant adjustments of the values in these two tensors to get the highest spearmans rank correlation from 2 lists I make from these 2 tensors while having PyTorch do the work? I just need a guide of where to go. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Spearman's Rank Correlation, but if I understand your question you're asking how to use PyTorch to solve problems other than deep networks?

If that's the case then I'll provide a simple least squares example which I believe should be informative to your effort.

Consider a set of 200 measurements of 10 dimensional vectors **x** and **y**. Say we want to find a linear transform from **x** to **y**.

The least squares approach dictates we can accomplish this by finding the matrix **M** and vector **b** which minimize |(**y** - (**M** **x**+**b**))²|

The following example code generates some example data and then uses pytorch to perform this minimization. I believe the comments are sufficient to help you understand what is occurring here.

```
import torch
from torch.nn.parameter import Parameter
from torch import optim

# define some fake data
M_true = torch.randn(10, 10)
b_true = torch.randn(10, 1)

x = torch.randn(200, 10, 1)
noise = torch.matmul(M_true, 0.05 * torch.randn(200, 10, 1))
y = torch.matmul(M_true, x) + b_true + noise

# begin optimization

# define the parameters we want to optimize (using random starting values in this case)
M = Parameter(torch.randn(10, 10))
b = Parameter(torch.randn(10, 1))

# define the optimizer and provide the parameters we want to optimize
optimizer = optim.SGD((M, b), lr=0.1)

for i in range(500):
    # compute loss that we want to minimize
    y_hat = torch.matmul(M, x) + b
    loss = torch.mean((y - y_hat)**2)

    # zero the gradients of the parameters referenced by the optimizer (M and b)
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    # compute new gradients
    loss.backward()

    # update parameters M and b
    optimizer.step()

    if (i + 1) % 100 == 0:
        # scale learning rate by factor of 0.9 every 100 steps
        optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr'] *= 0.9

        print('step', i + 1, 'mse:', loss.item())

# final parameter values (data contains a torch.tensor)
print('Resulting parameters:')
print(M.data)
print(b.data)

print('Compare to the "real" values')
print(M_true)
print(b_true)
```

Of course this problem has a simple closed form solution, but this numerical approach is just to demonstrate how to use PyTorch's autograd to solve problems not necessarily neural network related. I also choose to explicitly define the matrix M and vector b here rather than using an equivalent `nn.Linear` layer since I think that would just confuse things.

In your case you want to maximize something so make sure to negate your objective function before calling backward.

Comment: I appreciate your answer! However, I don't think is the concept I'm looking for. For example, if I were to solve this problem manually, I would go through each value one by one in each matrix and adjust the value by .1 (up or down), and then calculate the correlation between the two matrices and if the correlation is the highest correlation obtained so far, I would store the two matrices and then continue to the next value and adjust, correlate, and continue the process.